# Using slideToggle with table rows (nesting a div) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After reading around it seems that a good solution to using `slideToggle()` on table rows is to nest a div inside. I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

jQuery

```
function toggle_dropdown(entry_id) {

    $(".library-dropdown-animation").slideUp("slow"); // Slide up any that are open
    $(".library-edit-dropdown").style.display = "none"; // Set their table row displays to none
    $("#library-dropdown-animation-" + entry_id ).slideDown("slow"); // slide the clicked one down 
    $("#library-edit-dropdown" + entry_id ).style.display = "block"; // set it's parent table row's display to block
}
```

HTML

```
                        <tr class="library-item-header">
                            <td class="library-item-title" onclick="toggle_dropdown(123);" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($anime_id); ?>"><?php echo $anime_name; ?></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr id="library-edit-dropdown-123" class="library-edit-dropdown" style="display: none;">
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <div class="library-dropdown-animation" id="library-edit-animation-123">

                                </div>    
                            </td>                                    
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="library-item-header">
                            <td class="library-item-title" onclick="toggle_dropdown(124);" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($anime_id); ?>"><?php echo $anime_name; ?></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr id="library-edit-dropdown-124" class="library-edit-dropdown" style="display: none;">
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <div class="library-dropdown-animation" id="library-edit-animation-124">

                                </div>    
                            </td>                                    
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="library-item-header">
                            <td class="library-item-title" onclick="toggle_dropdown(125);" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($anime_id); ?>"><?php echo $anime_name; ?></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr id="library-edit-dropdown-125" class="library-edit-dropdown" style="display: none;">
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <div class="library-dropdown-animation" id="library-edit-animation-125">

                                </div>    
                            </td>                                    
                        </tr>
```

So essentially, I've got a `td` in another row that when it's clicked it slides it's content row (right beneath it) down while sliding any other row up. Since we can't use slide on table row (`hide()` and `show()` and `toggle()` works perfectly fine by the way) i've used a containing div that has content, in this example i've left the content out. In any case, clicking on the `td` does nothing using this jQuery.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wxu3E/

Comment: Please add your code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wxu3E/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/wxu3E/2/

i added the events on the Anchor itself not the row by adding a **class** to it, also I added attribute **entry_id**

```
<a href="#" entry_id="124" class="toggle_dropdown">Click</a>
```

and in the JQuery code the event will be attached to elements with class **toggle_dropdown**

```
$(".toggle_dropdown").click
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/LzaZT/

**Suggestion**: data-attributes might come in handy here... i have added data-attribute in your HTML, please look at the HTML carefully in jsfiddle.

```
data-id="123"
```

so your final Jquery looks like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".library-item-title", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var entry_id = $(this).data("id");
        toggleDropdown(entry_id);
    });

    function toggleDropdown(entry_id) {
        $(".library-edit-dropdown").slideUp("slow");
        $("#library-edit-dropdown-" + entry_id).slideDown("slow");
    }
```

**Error in your code:** you are missing `-` at the end in this line, as your DIV id deos contain `-`

```
$("#library-edit-dropdown" + entry_id ).style.display = "block";
```

try this fiddle for animation: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/LzaZT/1/

```
function toggleDropdown(entry_id) {
    $(".library-edit-dropdown").hide("slow");
    $("#library-edit-dropdown-" + entry_id).show("slow");
}
```

Comment: well, what version of jquery you are using.. might be browser issue. Fiddle i provided is working fine for me.

Comment: cant think of any issue with slide as it is working in fiddle. can you provide more info.. any error in console.

Comment: how should I deal with the parent `tr`? How can I hide / reveal it as the div's either slide down / slide up.